# How to replace string with fallback option?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

I would like to replace string with fallback option. for example

```
var x = " Hello {{first_name | fallback : 'User' }} "
var f_name = "ME";
```

in above case i want if f_name is defined then result will like this

```
Hello ME
```

other wise result will be

```
Hello User
```

so how can i do this?

Comment: Are you using any framework or view plugin for jQuery? Because that notation is not supported by JavaScript or jQuery itself.

Comment: I am using express framework

Comment: @Kirill because `"Hello " + (first_name || "User")` is more elegant :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

ES5 :

```
var x = "Hello " + (first_name || "User")
```

ES6 :

```
let x = ´Hello ${first_name || "User"}´
```

**Edit** after your new question in the comments : if you want to apply a `replace` or something :

```
var x = "Hello " + (first_name ? first_name.replace(/some.RegEx/g, '') : "User")
```

Comment: Thank You @Jeremy Thille :)

Comment: we can do more dynamic? I mean using regex or anything else?

Comment: ex : if f_name is defined than replace using a regex like  x.replace(here is the some regex code,f_name).

Comment: regex code will be replace (first_name || "User") to var value

Comment: Thank You SIr :)  can we do it more easily  like x.replace(/\{{first_name || [a-zA-Z]+}}/g, "ME")

Comment: in your answer we need to break  down after hello. i would like work with full string. i mean without " + "

Comment: Please give me  Suggestions

Comment: You're drifting to a totally different question. I have updated my answer before, even though it was already different from your original question, but you should ask a new question about the regex on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
x = x + (f_name === null ? "User" : f_name);
```

Comment: Double check it, this doesn't work as expected if f_name is not defined.

Comment: You are right. For this to work, f_name has to be defined. I misunderstood.